# How to interrupt a thread-safe algorithm that changes ready state?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a simple algorithm that goes like this:

1. `lock`, if state is `finished` or `started`, return - else set to `started`, `unlock`
2. do some work
3. `lock`, set state to `finished`, `unlock`
4. if error, `lock`, set state to `failed`, `unlock`

The work in step 2, specifically, is posting credentials and retrieving a JWT token. The algorithm gets executed each time the process performs a call to the web service.

The issue is that the JWT token expires in 72 hours, but the process running may last much longer.  So, I need to set a timer that resets state to `not started`, so that the process re-authenticates every 72 hours.

So the question is, how do I safely reset the state when there's a chance (however infinitesimally small) that the algorithm is in the `started` state when the timer fires and resets the state to `not started`.

Comment: can you share with us some of your code in order to better understand how your algorithm behave?

Comment: Do you want your question answered only by people who know what a "JWT token" is? If not, you need to explain your scenario more clearly, and more generally. Don't distract with details that are not actually pertinent to the specific issue at hand. It's also not clear at all what would be "unsafe" about simply changing the "state" to "not started" even when the state is currently "started". Please rework the question so that it is clearly stated. Provide a good [mcve], and describe _specifically_ what problem you're trying to avoid. What does the code do now, what do you want instead?